# Max "X" chars per line in TextView?

Tags: android, xml, xamarin

I would like to have max 5 char per line in my TextView, but I cannot find a way to do it.
I saw other related posts, but didn't find a solution...

Here's my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:importantForAccessibility="no"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">
    <TextView
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/numeroDial"
        android:textSize="97dp"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:importantForAccessibility="no"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="5"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:minLines="1"
        android:maxLines="3" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Any idea why it isn't working?

**EDIT**

I found out that if I remove `android:inputType="number"` my code works...how can I keep defining the inputType  but on multiple lines?

Comment: Add a listener to the text field.  Count the characters each time the value changes.  Truncate the result if it's longer than 5 characters.

Comment: @durbnpoisn Any idea to solve it just in xml?

Answer (score 1):

Use the maxLength attribute.

```
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/numeroDial" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:maxLength="5"/>
```

See [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:maxLength).

Comment: I just wrote a test app and it works. What Android version did you try this on?

Comment: Android 5.x, but I'm usig Xamarin to develop the app.

Comment: Solved, it was not working because of a bug in Xamarin...but your solution only limits the textView to show 5 chars, I want it to be able to take more chars, but I want them divided in multiple lines each long 5 chars...any idea?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this on multiple lines and still limit the length put the following two attributes in your xml for the EditText:

```
android:maxLength="5"
android:lines="2"
```

Comment: still does not work, I can write 5 chars and then nothing more...but when I don't define the inputType it works..

Comment: I use this in my app and it works. What exactly is your problem?

Comment: Let's say I want to enter 10 chars (only numbers), but I want them to be on two different lines (each long 5 chars)...how do I do that? The code I posted works perfectly if I remove `android:inputType="number"`, but I cannot remove it..